# Google Apps Minute Timer not Firing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-sheets-api

I am not a programmer, I am a teacher and instructional tech specialist. I am trying my best to figure out how to create some basic scripts to help streamline some processes at my school with Google Apps, and I am running into one very annoying and persistent issue. My colleague and I pieced together a script that creates calendar events from responses in a Google Sheet that is fed by a Google form. We are running the Copy Down add-on on the script in order to concatenate some fields that make up the description field of the calendar event, and the whole script works beautifully when run manually. We would like it to run every minute though so it catches any new submissions after copy down has run. The problem is that the trigger will not run, nor will it send us an error. There is nothing to debug. The script is below and I am wondering if anyone has any ideas to help us. We have tried writing the script for the minute timer into the script as indicated in another post, but it just makes duplicates of the trigger every minute until the it errors out. The script is below and any help would be greatly appreciated. I can't make this paste correctly, sorry.

```
    //insert your google calendar ID
var calendarId = "eths202.org_2d3933323533323433393439@resource.calendar.google.com";

//index (starting from 1) of each column in the sheet
var titleIndex = 15;
var descriptionIndex = 16;
var startDateIndex = 11;
var endDateIndex = 12;
var locationIndex = 10;
var googleCalendarIndex = 18;


/*
find the row where the Google Calendar Event ID is blank or null
The data of this row will be used to create a new calendar event
*/


function findRow(sheet) {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
 var values = dataRange.getValues();

 for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
 if(values[i][googleCalendarIndex-1]=="" || values[i][googleCalendarIndex-1]==null)
 newEvent(i+1);
 } 
 };


/* 
get the data of the new row by calling getSheetData() and 
create a new Calendar event by calling submitToGoogleCalendar()
*/

function newEvent(row){ 
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var eventId = submitToGoogleCalendar(getSheetData(sheet,row),null)
 if(eventId!=null) 
 sheet.getRange(row,googleCalendarIndex,1,1).setValue(eventId);
};


/* 
Store the data of a row in an Array
*/

function getSheetData(sheet,row)
{
 var data = new Array();

 data.title = sheet.getRange(row,titleIndex,1,1).getValue();
 data.description = sheet.getRange(row,descriptionIndex,1,1).getValue();
 data.startDate = sheet.getRange(row,startDateIndex,1,1).getValue();
 data.endDate = sheet.getRange(row,endDateIndex,1,1).getValue();
 data.location = sheet.getRange(row,locationIndex,1,1).getValue();

 return data; 
};

/* 
if a cell is edited in the sheet, get all the data of the corresponding row and 
create a new calendar event (after deleting the old event) by calling submitToGoogleCalendar() 
*/

function dataChanged(event){

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var row = event.range.getRow();

 var eventId = sheet.getRange(row,googleCalendarIndex,1,1).getValue();

 var eventId = submitToGoogleCalendar(getSheetData(sheet,row),eventId)

 if(eventId!=null)
 sheet.getRange(row,googleCalendarIndex,1,1).setValue(eventId);

};


/* 
This function creates an event in the Google Calendar and returns the calendar event ID 
which is stored in the last column of the sheet 
*/
function submitToGoogleCalendar(sheetData,eventId) {
 // some simple validations ;-)
 if(sheetData.title == "" || sheetData.startDate == "" || sheetData.startDate == null)
 return null;

 var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
 var start = new Date(sheetData.startDate);
 var end = new Date(sheetData.endDate);
 //end.setHours(23);
//end.setMinutes(59);
 //end.setSeconds(59);

 // some simple date validations
 if(start > end)
 return null;

 var event = null;

 //if eventId is null (when called by newEvent()) create a new calendar event
 if(eventId==null)
 {
 event = cal.createEvent(sheetData.title, start, end, {
 description : sheetData.description, 
 location: sheetData.location,
 });
 return event.getId(); 
 }
 /*
 else if the eventid is not null (when called by dataChanged()), delete the calendar event 
 and create a new event with the modified data by calling this function again
 */
 else
 {
 event = cal.getEventSeriesById(eventId);
 event.deleteEventSeries(); 
 return submitToGoogleCalendar(sheetData,null);
 }

 return event.getId();

};
```

Comment: You should use an "On Form Submit" trigger.  It's not good to create a trigger that runs every minute in your situation.  An "On Form Submit" can be installed in a G Form a G Sheet, or both.  There are two types of triggers, simple and installable.  You need to "install" a trigger, which just means, that while inside of the code editor, click on the "Resources" menu, and then click on the "Current project's triggers" menu item, and add a new trigger.  If you already installed a trigger to run every minute, then obviously you already knew that. :)

Comment: Thanks, Sandy. The reason that we need to use the minutes timer is that we are using Copy Down, which needs to run before the script so we have the correct fields for the calendar event. In our experience, the On Form Submit trigger happens so quickly that our Copy Down doesn't get to run. If you know of a way of making Copy Down run first and then the form submit trigger, that would solve this problem. We just haven't gotten that to work. Thanks!

Comment: Does your spreadsheet contain multiple sheets? If so, perhaps the trigger is grabbing the wrong one with `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()`. Also, I'd recommend you call `throw "Test Error";` at the top of your `findRow` function to see if it gets reported to your email. If that works, then try `throw sheet.getName();` right below `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()`.